# Microsoft Graph API Permissions - revoking permissions won't revoke previous connections

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, powerapps, power-automate

This question is meant directly for GRAPH, not any particular programming language.

I just made my self a custom connector and I have a Graph call that creates a Microsoft Team.
Now when I make the connection before granting the permission in the Azure for the registered application, my call gets 403 response.[image: 403 Response] and that is absolutely ok! No permission has been granted yet.

Ok then, now I add the Delegated permission of Teams.Create and consent and save. If I try to create the make the call now it still gets the same 403 response. When I create a new connection (basically sign in again) [image: New Connection] it works. But the old one still does not.

This does not bother me that much, but if it is vice versa, that makes me nervous. Let's say your application goes crazy for some reason so you go to registered applications and you revoke all of it's permissions and consents. But, even if you do so, and there was a connection made before you revoked permissions and cancelled the consents, it still has all the rights to create the team in my example.

Can you please explain me how this stuff actually works? Is this intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out to us, this is mostly due to cached token, when you connected without having proper permission , that token has been cached with the previous scopes you have that's why you are getting  403 response. when you create a new connection the new refresh token has been used with newly provided permissions.

Thanks

Comment: I tried today and it seems it does not work anymore. Do you how long it takes for cache to stop working?

Comment: Hi Marek , sorry i didn't get that as you said ,"it seems it does not work anymore." what it means ,could you please confirm if your first connection still not working ?

Comment: If it still fails , please provide us the request id and timestamp of your failed call after providing the required permission and also let us know how your are obtaining access token . thanks

Comment: I meant it vice versa - the ones that worked stopped working after revoking permissions, all good I think, thanks